# Python interpreter resolve regex

Tags: python

In a script called generator.py i have this line of code:

```
    arg=''

for i,a in enumerate(sys.argv):
    if(i!=0):
        arg+=a+" "
```

if i print arg i can see the shell argument minus the script's name

And it was fine but if a use a regex line *.h i discovered that the interpreter resolve this rule for me and dispite *.h printing a i can see:

```
file.h file2.h .... filen.h
```

My question is how can i get the non resolved command line string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the script from command line, which resolves the glob for you and passes the result to the python script.

If you don't want the glob resolved by the command line, just escape the wildcard `*`.

Your shell is expanding the `*` to its meaning of wildcard.

Possible solutions are passing `"*.h"`, `'*.h'` or `\*.h` from the command line to your script, which will receive the exact `*.h` string.

As @SpoonMeiser suggested, you can check what your script receives by using this:

```
echo script.py arg1 arg2 blahblah
```

This will print back what is effectively called after the expansion of the glob and give you an idea of what happened.

Also thanks to @SpoonMeiser for giving the concept of glob for this case, that you can look more in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax)

Comment: The best way to demonstrate this problem, I think, would be to enter something like this on the commandline: `echo myscript.py *.h`, which would show how the shell interprets it before the script actually runs. It's also worth pointing out that this is a glob, not a regex.

Comment: Never thought of that `echo myscript.py *.h`, it's nice. I didn't know what a `glob` was (just called everything regexp) either till now, thank you!

Comment: I think this deserves to be marked as an answer, @P.Carlino

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you probably can't catch it - the  arguments to script get resolved on an os level before they are passed to sys.argv.